# How to fix PHP warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ffmpeg.dll'

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to install the ffmpeg extension in WampServer for Windows. I have copied all files in particular folders as described here https://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/installing-ffmpeg-wamp.

But I am getting the following errors in Apache error log and library is not loading in phpinfo()

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext/php_ffmpeg.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
>   
>   **Warning**:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext/php_ffmpeg.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>    in **Unknown** on line **0**

Why am I getting this error?
I tried upgrading PHP version but it has no effect on it.

How can I fix this PHP startup issue?

Comment: I have added extension=php_ffmpeg.dll but still showing same error

Comment: You've installed the wrong dll for the version of PHP you have installed. It needs to be specific to your version of PHP (i.e. 5.4,5.5,5.6,7.0,7.1,etc) 32-bit, 64-bit, zts or non-zts and finally built with the same VC version.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because the path to the dll is wrong. Without looking at your file system we can't provide the correct path. Check the path `ext/php_ffmpeg.dll` against the path of your other `dll`s that are loading. It has been awhile since I ran PHP on Windows but you could try something like [dependencywalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find the complete path that is attempting to be loaded. You might also have an issue if you are on a 64bit system (sysWOW64 I think). Also, double check you renamed php_ffmpeg_20050618.dll.